# "no matching function for call" when trying to cin.read into a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, io, cin

Pixel is a structure containing 3 characters. 
`struct Pixel { char r, g, b} ;`

```
int H = 5, C = 10;
Pixel *PMatrix[H]; // Creates an array of pointers to pixels
for (int h = 0 ; r < H ; h++) {
    PMatrix[r] = new Pixel[C]; //Each row points to an array of pixels
}
```

I have a PPM file, and I'm trying to read the bytes into my matrix of pixels for an image representation, row by row.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    cin.read(PMatrix[i][0], width*3);
}
```

I've also tried `"cin.read(PMatrix[i], width*3);"` in the loop.

I get the error `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::read(PpmImage::Pixel&, unsigned int)'`

What does this mean???

Comment: Has nothing to do with using an array, and everything to do with trying to pass a user-defined type (`Pixel`). `read` may not be the right function for you. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Comment: It should be `&PMatrix[i][0]` or just `PMatrix[i]` with some `reinterpret_cast<char*>` thrown in. But I guess it will still fail at runtime (because of the alignment?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you have a class you created and you're passing it to a standard library function that doesn't have an overload for it. `PMatrix` is a `Pixel*[]`, so using `[]` once gets a `Pixel*`, and again gives a `Pixel`. `cin.read` doesn't know anything about a `Pixel` and has no operator to deal with it.

Usually, one would overload `operator>>` for their class and `istream`.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& lhs, Pixel& rhs)
{
    lhs >> rhs.r >> rhs.g >> rhs.b;
    return lhs;
}

//...

cin >> PMatrix[i][0]; //calls our overloaded operator
```

I'm not sure, but I think you might have been trying to do this:

```
cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(PMatrix[i]), 3); //ew magic number
```

Since `Pixel` is a POD type you can cast it to a pointer to the first element. This would read three `char`s and store them into `PMatrix[i][0]`. I recommend using the first method, though. It's more idiomatic and looks less unstable.

Comment: But then how would I add the other pixels that are pointed to by the array? Why can't I do `cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(PMatrix[i]), 5*3);` to read in 5 pixels at once?

Comment: @user Use a nested loop to loop over that array. The struct can have packing bytes after the rgb. Your Pixel is probably 4 bytes long when only 3 bytes are data.